# Same ymin in loglogscale

Tags: pgfplots

I want to obtain the same y axis for multiple plots.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xmode=log,ymode=log,ymin=0,ymax=450, log ticks with fixed point,
]
\addplot table {
1 10
2 20
4 25
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xmode=log,ymode=log,ymin=0,ymax=450, log ticks with fixed point,
]
\addplot table {
1 100
2 200
4 450
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the figures above, the y axes are not same although the `ymax` and `ymin` values are same.

Comment: Did you read the warnings output by the compiler? They tell you exactly what the problem is: you cannot apply 0 as a minimum for a log axis because it's not finite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check your `.log` file, you'll see the following warning:

```
Ignoring illegal input argument ymin=0: cannot apply log.
```

You can't take the logarithm of 0, which is why the `ymin` value is ignored and the lowest data value is used for determining the lower bound instead.

Using a positive value for `ymin` fixes the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xmode=log,ymode=log,
   ymin=5,ymax=450,
   log ticks with fixed point,
]
\addplot table {
1 10
2 20
4 25
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xmode=log,ymode=log,
   ymin=5, ymax=450,
   log ticks with fixed point,
]
\addplot table {
1 100
2 200
4 450
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```